# Why does this mapping of g to gj give "'Undefined variable gj"?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, lua

> ```
> E121: Undefined variable : gj
> E121: Undefined variable : gk
> ```

```
local keymap = vim.keymap.set
local default_opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
local expr_opts = { noremap = true, expr = true, silent = true }

-- these two work as expected
-- keymap({ "n", "v" }, "k", "v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k'", expr_opts)
-- keymap({ "n", "v" }, "j", "v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j'", expr_opts)
-- these two throw the error from above
keymap({ "n", "v" }, "j", "gj", expr_opts)
keymap({ "n", "v" }, "k", "gk", expr_opts)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using `expr_opts` which has `expr = true`. That means to create an `<expr>` mapping, like (ignoring visual and select modes)

```
:nnoremap <expr> j gj
```

which doesn't work either. Use the non-expr options:

```
:nnoremap j gj
```